# How to connect a list of button signals ? - Godot 4.1.1

Tags: signals, godot, gdscript, godot4

I want to connect the pressed signal of 9 buttons by code but since the .connect method doesn’t use a string argument (which I could easily modify in my loop) I don’t know how to connect each of them.

I want to do something like this:

```
for i in buttonArray:
    get_node("button%d" %i).pressed.connect("on_pressed_button_%d" %i)
```

Expecting it will connect the 9 pressed signals to my 9 on_pressed_button function

I found a post for an older Godot version that use only one "on_pressed" function for the whole list and get the button in the parameter.

```
for button in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("my_buttons"):
    button.connect("pressed", self, "_some_button_pressed", [button])

func _some_button_pressed(button):
    print(button.name)
```

Is something like this still possible in the actual 4.1 version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using Callables and the `call(String)` function.

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    for button in $ButtonList.get_children():
        button.pressed.connect(func(): call("on_pressed_"+button.name) )

func on_pressed_Button1():
    print("1")
func on_pressed_Button2():
    print("2")
func on_pressed_Button3():
    print("3")
func on_pressed_Button4():
    print("4")
func on_pressed_Button5():
    print("5")
```

Doing this works but requires you to have a function for each button and is name sensitive (you could work around this using the index like you started doing).

---

The other way of doing it like you said is connecting all the buttons to a single function and passing the button as an argument. You can do this with the `bind` function.

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    for button in $ButtonList.get_children():
        button.pressed.connect(on_pressed.bind(button))

func on_pressed(button):
    print(button.name)
```

This adds the button as an argument to the Callable.